# CameraRoll on Android

Tags: react-native, camera-roll

Is there anybody who used the [CameraRoll API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html) for Android devices? Is Android supported ?
I used the example from the docs, but it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to request the permission for that. Call a function like the one below (on your react-native project) and call it if your app runs on Android (`Platform.OS === 'Android' ? this.requestPhotosPermission() : this.getPhotos()`)

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native'

async requestPhotosPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        this.getPhotos();
      } else {
        console.log("Photos permission denied")
      }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

it is worked for me

[CameraRollExample](https://github.com/blessingoraz/cameraRollExample)